# Batch convert Shell Script for ImageMagick

Tags: javascript, html, bash, shell, imagemagick

I want to batch convert / loop through all images within the folder "/input" and then optimise all the images and finally output them in the folder "/output".

How can I do something similar to this:

```
convert /Users/james/Desktop/image-magick/santorini.jpg -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 75 -resize 700x466! -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB -background white -flatten /Users/james/Desktop/image-magick/final/santorini-opt.jpg
```

^ Currently with the above script, I have to run manually for every image, one at a time!

How can I do something similar using shell script to do it all for me in bulk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer is almost correct. Also use -strip first before any other settings or they will be lost. Also current versions of ImageMagick use -colorspace sRGB unless you want the darker linear RGB colorspace. The following has proper ImageMagick syntax to strip, convert to sRGB, resize and then set all the jpg output settings.

```
cd path2/inputdirectory
mogrify -strip -colorspace sRGB -resize "700x466!" -background white -flatten -interlace JPEG -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -quality 75 -path /Users/james/Desktop/image-magick/final/ *.jpg
```

Note that JPG does not support transparency, so I am not sure why you have -background white -flatten in the command. That would be appropriate if your input were png (i.e. *.png or just * to handle all formats)

Comment: ah right, thanks - i wasn't too sure what half the commands i had were doing. I will remove the bg white and flatten. Above works perfectly and saves and additional 20KB. Thanks :-)

Comment: just wanted to ask, is there a way to resize by a % based ration or something rather than specifying an exact size? Also what does -interlace do and -sampling-factor 4:2:0 not sure if these settings are right or what they actually do?

Comment: You can resize using %. So -resize 50x75% would resize to 50% width and 75% of height. https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry If you want to do that exactly and not preserve aspect, you can add ! to the command, but it might distort the image. Interlace means the image will be drawn in interlace format, like window blinds as it displays. -sampling factor changes the ratio of YUV JPG channel compressions. https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#interlace and https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#sampling-factor

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`mogrify`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) command instead of `convert`.
Use `-path` option to create output images in a specific directory. If you don't, your original images will be overwritten.

```
mogrify -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 75 -resize 700x466! -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB -background white -flatten -path /Users/james/Desktop/image-magick/final/ /Users/james/Desktop/image-magick/*.jpg
```

Comment: Tried to copy your script and run it (changed the paths), but i get: unable to open image './input/*.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3335.

Comment: @John strange, I tried it on a bunch of .jpg files without issues. Are you sure there are any .jpg files into the ./input/ directory ? Did you run it in a terminal or through a shell script ?

Comment: through terminal calling the shell script. Yes images are in the input folder

Comment: Which OS do you use ?

Comment: I use MAC Yoesmite

Comment: You may first try to launch the command directly from your `./input/` folder with `*.jpg` final argument

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165164/discussion-between-fredg-and-john).